# Driver is not intended for this platform?

Tags: windows-7

I've downloaded a special hybrid version for 32bit/64bit but my Windows 7 keeps saying "Driver is not intended for this platform"? What can I do? I've tried to install with the setup.exe and with the device manager method selecting the driver info file with the file selector but both method failed to install the driver. I always get the title? My box is a laptop and I've already had difficult to install the latest video card driver from the source but I solved this with overide the old driver with the new driver in the old installer? But with the new chipset driver and new hard disk driver I don't have the old installer? Do I need it? My windows is already in testmode and I tried to disable the integrity checks:`bcedit -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` to no avail.

When I tried the old driver from the source I get the same error message. Currently installed is the Windows 7 driver from sp1 from 21.06.2006? I looked into the new driver package from AMD and there are 2 folder W7 and W764A. I think W764 is for 64 bit so I tried to install it but Windows insist on a better driver? When I start the setup of the W7 folder I get an error message "the driver is not intended for this platform"?

Comment: @Downvoters: Why downvote? Please explain?

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong driver for your platform. :)  IE: you're running a 32-bit driver on a 64-Windows.  Perhaps include some information about you version of Windows, the driver you are attempting to install, and the make/model of the notebook in question.  And some Line-breaks. :) As is, it's hard to read, and follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. I've tried to update the hard disk driver in the device manager. But my box has a Raid-Controller with an extra tree in the device manager. Now I've update the Raid-Controller in the extra tree with the new driver and it is showing the current version. In the hard disk section the driver date is still from 2006 but I guess this isn't so important.